# Laravel API Resources: Different returns based on user role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is the first time I am using Api Resource in Laravel 5.8 to return data to an application. There is a `User` model contains some public and private information about a user. A user is allowed to see all his/her information  (same as name, phone number, email, ...) but others are allowed to see only the name and username. How can I handle this in Api Resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes)

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'username' => $this->username,
        'email' => $this->when(auth()->id() == $this->id, 'email'),
        'phone_number' => $this->when(auth()->id() == $this->id, 'phone'),
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
}
```

This would only return the email and phone number when the authenticated user is trying to see his own information